# How do you open the native map app from the browser?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-mobile, web

This is a simple task on iPhone as it hijacks google map urls automatically. Android you use the geo protocol, blackberry has a bit of JS.  How can you do this on WP7? From what I can tell it is not possible but hopefully someone out there knows more than me! To be clear I am talking about opening the native map app from the browser, not another app.

Comment: This might also be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've documented my findings here:

http://www.habaneros.com/blog/posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx

Comment: His updated post - even better: http://habaneroconsulting.com/Blog/Posts/Translating_schema_org_s_postalAddress_microdata_into_useful_links_for_mobile.aspx

Comment: Link is now http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser#.VBleZGRdVr0

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten the maps app to open from within my app by opening up a WebBrowser, so I'm guessing this will work straight from the webbrowser. Obviously you'll need to modify it to use JS, but the code is simple and you'll be able to understand what's going on.

```
string location = "maps:" + SelectedLocation.Street + " " + SelectedLocation.PostalCode;
location = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(location);
TaskHelper.WebPage(location);
```

Additionally, the bing maps probably supports routes in the same way it does via a normal URL:

from [Build your own URL](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx) :

```
    The following example shows a route on the map from a specific address to a specific point: 
http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&rtp=adr.One%20Microsoft Way,%20Redmond,%20WA%2098052~pos.45.23423_-122.1232_MyPlace
```

Comment: If you have a WP7 you can try these [links](http://proto01.flightdeckmedia.com/wp7.html). Let me know if either work, unfortunately I don't have a device for testing right now.

Comment: sure does, check here for some screenshots (confirm & maps) https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8&resid=EF08824B672FB5D8!343

Comment: Yes it appears those work! the code is:

    <a href="maps:vancouver v5l4g1" >txt</a>
    <a href="maps:49.275267 -122.988617" >txt</a>

Now the question is why couldn't I find this documented anywhere?!

Thanks willme

Comment: Any ideas on plotting a route? I tried the maps.bing parameters but they didn't seem to work.  I tried:
'<a href="maps:?rtp=~adr.518 Beatty St Vancouver BC"></a>`
On maps.bing that goes to the directions view with Beatty Street as the destination and the starting point blank.

Comment: @JohnAllan check out this link: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx

Comment: tried that out, those urls work on bing.com but not on app, at least not using the maps: protocol. Thanks for looking though